# Dynamically set varnish ip address to nginx set_real_ip_from

Tags: docker, nginx, varnish

I've setup docker containers (Nginx, Varnish, PHP-FPM) and they all communicate with each other. However I want to setup php-fpm status page and want to be accessible by localhost (127.0.0.1) and a monitoring service on a different docker container.

My initial setup on nginx works

```
location = /status {
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend;
}
```

However when I add allow/deny (see below), I cannot access the page via local host.

```
allow 127.0.0.1;
deny all;
```

Digging around, it looks like nginx is receiving the varnish ip. So I've added the following, and it works.

```
set_real_ip_from    XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;
real_ip_header      X-Forwarded-For;
```

How do I add the varnish IP address dynamically into the nginx conf file?
I've tried `set_real_ip_from     <docker container name>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update nginx version to > 1.13.1 and call varnish server using hostname. in this case, the varnish server was sitting on a hostname of `site-varnish`.

Was able to use `set_real_ip_from    site-varnish;`